# JVM gc log not rotating

Tags: java, rotation, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm using solaris 10, Wildfly 10 and java 1.8.0_66.

I thought to make gc log rotating, as long as I set the following parameters:

```
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles
-XX:GCLogFileSize
-Xloggc
```

it should rotate.

I set jvm params to be

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -verbosegc -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=50 -XX:GCLogFileSize=5K -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/mylocation/standalone/log/gc.log"
```

It does not rotate. It seems that I have to add param `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` to make gc log file rotate.

Did my understanding wrong? or did I miss any settings so it doesn't rotate?

Thanks, Helen

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not rotate", does that mean a file is created and no rotation is done? Or does it mean that no file is created?

Comment: only the first gc file `gc.log.0.current` is created, and the file size increase with gc logs. but even when `gc.log.0.current` file size exceed 5k, it does not rotate to new file, it remains using the same file `gc.log.0.current` and the file size keeps growing. no other gc files ever created.

Comment: it seems gc log file size minimum is 8K, so when I set to be 5K, jvm set to be default 8K. that maybe the reason it does not rotate at 5K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've already figured that out yourself. `GCLogFileSize` has the minimum value of 8KB in JDK, even if you try to set less. Here is the relevant fragment from [HotSpot sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/e765322578aa/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l2023):

```
  if (UseGCLogFileRotation && (GCLogFileSize != 0) && (GCLogFileSize < 8*K)) {
    FLAG_SET_CMDLINE(uintx, GCLogFileSize, 8*K);
    jio_fprintf(defaultStream::output_stream(),
                "GCLogFileSize changed to minimum 8K\n");
  }
```

Comment: You can also refer to oracle documentation [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#DebuggingOptions)